# "In the sequel" - outdated mathematical jargon or precise technical term?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

**Possible Duplicate:** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907/correct-usage-of-the-phrase-in-the-sequel-history-alternatives

As a non-native speaker of English, I have been perplexed by the phrase "in the sequel" as used in textbooks, lecture notes, and even research articles. None of my linguistically inclined native speaker friends have seen it outside of mathematical literature, and the relevant Oxford English Dictionary definition of "sequel" suggests mathematical usage is non-standard:

> The ensuing narrative, discourse, etc.; the following or remaining part of a narrative, etc.; that which follows as a continuation; esp. a literary work that, although complete in itself, forms a continuation of a preceding one.

What I've inferred from context is that it means something along the lines of "for the rest of this book/paper/text", especially as it's usually used to introduce notation and/or convention.

Some examples:

> We hope that the relation between linear transformations and matrices
>   is by now sufficiently clear that the reader will not object if **in the sequel**,
>   when we wish to give examples of linear transformations with various
>   properties, we content ourselves with writing down a matrix.

--Paul Halmos, Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces, p. 86

> [Here, and **in the sequel**, Card(S) denotes the number of elements in the
>   finite set S.]

--J.P. Serre, Local Fields, p. 64

> **In the sequel** we shall denote by 
>   ∅ the empty set and by {pt} a set with 
>   one element.

-- Pierre Schapira, Algebra and Topology course notes, p. 8

> **In the sequel**, we will denote 
>   by L(C ) the configuration space of any convergent CFG C.

--E. Goles et. al., Sandpile Models and Lattices: a comprehensive survey, Theoretical Computer Science, 2004, Vol 322, Issue 2, p. 398

So my actual question is two-fold.

1. What does the phrase actually mean?
2. When is its use warranted over the use of phrases such as "for the rest of the book/paper/text"?

Comment: It means exactly what the OED says it means.

Comment: Neither I am a native English speaker, thus my authority on the subject is minimal, but I always took "in the sequel" as an expression more or less equivalent to "from now on" (maybe just less colloquial). 

Anyway, this seems to belong more to EnglishOverflow then to MathOverflow...... :-)

Comment: .. This was also on mathunderflow, where Pete Clark gave a satisfactory answer to it.

Comment: I wonder why was this copied from Math.SE?

Comment: Indeed, it is because of this brilliant answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907/correct-usage-of-the-phrase-in-the-sequel-history-alternatives/924#924 that I gained the ability to comment on posts at Math.SE.  I agree that it is a little curious that this question appeared here less than a day after it got asked and answered on the other site.  

Comment: Too early for a sequel, we could say!

Comment: Eh? Am I the only one here to regularly use it in papers and notes? 

Comment: It means exactly the same as "for the rest of the paper". It's a matter of personal preference which you use. Another slightly old-fashioned option is "in what follows". I have a slight aversion to "in the sequel" because it strikes me as a tad pretentious and potentially confusing to some readers. What if someone was thrown off by thinking of a sequel to the paper, like a sequel to a movie? 

Comment: @Tom: I agree. Since the word "sequel" seems to mostly be used these days to refer to movie sequels, there is maybe a small amount of danger of misinterpretation by a modern reader, who might think it is referring to a future book or paper.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question.

Comment: Having cast the closing vote, I would say that as this question has appeared on math.SE and had a very good answer there, there is no reason for it to reappear here.  If I could "close as duplicate", referring to the math.SE question, then I would have done so (closing-as-duplicate requires me to specify a duplicate question _on MO_).

Answer (score 6):

It means "from now on." (Such as, "in the sequel, $K$ will denote a perfect field...") This does, in fact, tend to appear only in older books, or in books in translation. I also was confused when I first saw the term.

Answer (score 3):

From [Online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=sequel&searchmode=none)

**sequel:**
    early 15c., "train of followers," from O.Fr. sequelle, from L.L. sequela "that which follows, result, consequence," from sequi "to follow," from PIE base *sekw- (cf. Skt. sacate "accompanies, follows," Avestan hacaiti, Gk. hepesthai "to follow," Lith. seku "to follow," L. secundus "second, the following," O.Ir. sechim "I follow"). Meaning "consequence" is attested from late 15c. Meaning "story that follows and continues another" first recorded 1510s.

Comment: So maybe you can also use it as "The sequel of this theorem is that this and that happen." or in "As a sequel of the intermediate value theorem you can ascertain the existence of solutions of many equations."

Answer (score 3):

I have always understood "in the sequel" to mean "in what follows". I have never checked but I assumed this was from the Latin as in "sequence" and "non sequitur"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur

In the usage you refer to it means what follows in the same article. The sequel to a film is the next film.

I see Franklin has checked the etymology.

Comment: Related also is the Latin abbreviation *et seq.*, which means "and what follows." Use it like this, "For a summary of this fact, see Lemma 2.11 et seq. in Fakename's article." 

Comment: Right. This is an abbreviation for "et sequitur"; similarly we have et al. for "et aliter" (and others) and etc. for "et cetera" (and things).

Comment: Actually, it is 'et sequens'. The verb is 'sequor'. 'Sequitur' is the third person singular form from which 'sequitur' the noun is derived. 'Sequens' is the present active participle. This is not just a quibble on etymology: 'sequitur' the noun has a specific meaning as logically following, whereas 'sequens' the participle just means "following" in general. So as 'et seq.' is usually used to refer to  the "narrative which follows", a reader thinking of "et sequitur" runs the risk of finding a *non sequitur*. =) Okay, this is getting too much to be LatinOverflow...

Comment: (Okay, I can't resist: I was taught that 'et al.' expands to 'et alii/aliae/alia' for people, and 'et alibi' for places. I don't recall the word 'aliter', so I looked it up, and it seems to be the adverb meaning 'otherwise'.)

Comment: (I can't resist either: which people would you refer to as “alia”?)

Comment: @Emil My guess is that "et alii" and "et alia" would both translate to "and another"; the difference being the first refers to a male and the second to a female.

Comment: @Bruce: No, you missed the point. “Alii” is masculine (though it could also be used for a group with mixed or unknown gender), and “aliae” is feminine, these are fine for people. But “alia” is *neuter*. People are not neuter in Latin. (Unlike many other IE languages, even words denoting kids such as “puer”, “puella” or “infans” have non-neuter gender in Latin.)

Comment: @Emil, I did miss the point. So "et alia" cannot be used to refer to people. I don't know what does or does not have a gender in Latin. What about gods and spiritual beings?

Comment: Grammatical gender is to a large degree arbitrary, so there are no hard and fast rules. However, sentient beings (gods and whatnot) are generally treated the same as humans, i.e., they have non-neuter gender, which agrees with their sex (if they have one).